# How to install and use open-iconic with bootstrap 4 beta using CDN library?

Tags: bootstrap-4, iconic

I have included below

```
<!-- Bootstrap 4.0 Beta -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-m/h/cUDAhf6/iBRixTbuc8+Rg2cIETQtPcH9D3p2Kg0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!-- open-iconic-bootstrap (icon set for bootstrap) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-BJ/G+e+y7bQdrYkS2RBTyNfBHpA9IuGaPmf9htub5MQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

And used this as below with no luck

```
<span class="oi oi-icon-person" title="person" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Answer (score 20):

Use `oi-person` class instead of `oi-icon-person`:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.0 Beta -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-m/h/cUDAhf6/iBRixTbuc8+Rg2cIETQtPcH9D3p2Kg0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!-- open-iconic-bootstrap (icon set for bootstrap) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-BJ/G+e+y7bQdrYkS2RBTyNfBHpA9IuGaPmf9htub5MQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<span class="oi oi-person" title="person" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Comment: What if I want to use it for offline purpose??

Comment: Do you need the entire directory? font, png, sprite, svg, webp? Theres a lot of files in there.

Answer (score 1):

For installing Iconic manually, you need to create a CSS folder and move `open-iconic-bootstrap.css` file inside it.

If we open the file, we can see what we need exactly (`src: url('../fonts/open-iconic.eot');`). Just move fonts folder in `../` and it's working !